# How can I unescape html in Java if the value stored is missing the semicolon?

Tags: java, html, escaping

I'm trying to convert an html value stored in a database to the corresponding special character when it prints to a file.  The value stored in the database is &#174.  If I execute StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml("&#174"), I simply get "&#174" output to the file.  However, if I do StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml("&#174 ;") then the registered symbol is output to the file.  Is there a library/function I'm unaware of that will unescape the html even if it is missing the semi colon?

Comment: Of course not, that input format is just bizarre and not a standard anywhere. Just add the semi-colon. `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(thingYouGotFromDb + ";")`.

Comment: If you know that adding the missing semicolon will fix the issue, why don't you programmatically just add it? eG check if the String ends with a semicolon and if not add it before passing it into the unescapeHtml method.

Comment: We don't know ahead of time when the value will present itself, and there are also other html values stored in the database.  It's also concatenated with a larger string value.  It's looking more like I'll just need a home grown solution.